# Compare sum of squares between two sets of numbers

Tags: inequality

I have two sets of numbers satisfying:
$x_1+x_2+...+x_n >= y_1+y_2+...+y_n$
Whether it is the case:
$x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2 >= y_1^2+y_2^2+...+y_n^2$
($x_i^2$ presents the square of xi).
$x_i, y_i$ here are not negative numbers.

Comment: Clearly not.  Take $0<x_i<-y_i$.

Comment: I edited my question. Numbers here are not negative

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. Consider for example $x_1 = \ldots = x_n = 1$, $y_1 = n$  and $y_2 = \ldots y_n = 0$.

Generally speaking, if $x_1 + \ldots + x_n = K$ are nonnegative numbers, then $x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2$ can assume any value between $\frac{K^2}{n}$ and $K^2$. The lower bound is attained iff all $x_1$ are equal to $\frac{K}{n}$ and the upper bound is achieved for $x_1 = K$, $x_2 = \ldots = x_n = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I have a WRONG approach to this problem but I don't know what is wrong, Since

$x_{1}+x_{2}\ldots+x_{n}\ge y_{1}+y_{2}\ldots+y_{n}$

We take integral of both side, due to the Monotony of integral:

$\frac{1}{2}\int(x_{1}+x_{2}\ldots+x_{n})dx \ge \frac{1}{2}\int(y_{1}+y_{2}\ldots+y_{n})dy$

This is a linear combination so:

$\frac{1}{2}\int x_{1}dx_{1}+\ldots +\frac{1}{2}\int x_{n}dx_{n} \ge \frac{1}{2}\int y_{1}dy_{1}+\ldots +\frac{1}{2}\int y_{n}dy_{n}$

Thus

$x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2+\ldots+x_{n}^2 \ge y_{1}^2+y_{2}^2+\ldots+y_{n}^2$

What is wrong here?

Comment: Check: You're integrating wrt what over what domain?

Comment: @Macavity I'm integrating wrt to random variables x and y in domain [0,+oo]. If I write this way: $\sum x \ge \sum y => \int \sum x \ge \int \sum y$

Comment: And why do you think that would hold true?